# How to stop the for loop inside useEffect in react js?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect, react-context, metamask

I am calling a function in useEffect and running a for loop with 50 iteration in that function.

Each iteration fetches some data, so it takes some time to fully complete for loop.

But before completing that for loop, If I again call the useEffect, then the for loop keeps going.

I want that for loop to stop and start another loop when calling useEffect again.

```
const getData = async () => {
        const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(accountId).call();
        setBalance(balance);
        let storeList = [];
        for (let i = 0; i<balance; i++) {
            try {   
                const token = await contract.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(accountId , i).call();
                let data = await contract.methods.tokenURI(token).call();
                const receivedData = await fetch(data);
                let jsonData = await receivedData.json();
                storeList.push(jsonData);
                storeList.sort((a, b) => a.tokenId-b.tokenId);
                setList([...storeList]);
            } catch(error) {
                cogoToast.error(`Error caused in fetching data of ${i} number token`);
            }
        }
        setList(storeList);
    };

useEffect(() => { 
        if (contract) getData(); 
    }, [contract]);
```

Now, when i run the useEffect again, then I want to completely abort the previous useEffect.

Right now, when i run useEffect again, the data of previous for loop is getting store in my list state and so my frontend side shows me the data of previous user in my current user.

Comment: You should use a cleanUp function in your useEffect to stop the loop: `useEffect(()=>{return myCleanUpFunction}, [dependencies])`

Comment: what should i add in cleanup function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    if (contract) getData(); 

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [contract]);
```

The clean up function returns [axios's Cancellation method](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)

This might not work, since you are looping 50 times, sending 50 requests